# When would we extract verb phrases from a text?

Tags: nlp, machine-learning

I have come across plenty of material on extracting noun phrases from text. Noun phrases were defined as adjacent NN/NNS/NNP/NNPS modified by an optional JJ. It is easy to note that noun phrases are extracted to get a sense of what the text is all about and to may be generate a tag/cloud of words, or to display the distribution of noun phrases for a text corpus.

On the otherhand, what are the scenarios when a verb phrase would need to be extracted? What business problems exists that necessitate for the extraction of verb phrases?

Thanks
Abhishek S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On case is to extract Predicates, in most SOV langauges it is sequence of NOUN VERB NOUN. Predicate is more descriptive then pure nouns and can be used for sentiments,

Comment: Not only for sentiments, the predicate is your best bet in classifying whole sentences.